# how to sort the table in mean stack angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, mean-stack

[image]I am using angular I  need to sort the table now its sorting but its only sorting depends upon pagination .I want sorting over all the data from all pagination .
anyone help!!!!

```
  <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='LastName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">LastName</a></th>
```

Comment: your question is not clear please update question with relevant code it does not make scene :)

Comment: Hi @BOSS able to understand now

Comment: are you using any data table ?

Comment: no only using html table and using ng-repeater to bind table

Comment: this might be because you applied the sorting on the array which contains only 1st (respective) page data only.

Comment: any other possible solution for that @SurjeetBhadauriya

Comment: can you put your code in the question where you do sorting so that i can be helpful.

Comment: your question is still not visible for us to edit